# ios swfit - assign list of AnyObject to dictionary key

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

so i want to assign a list of AnyObject to a key of a dictionary with the structure [String:AnyObject]

here is my code:

```
let list = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: newData, options: .allowFragments) as! [AnyObject]
                let parsedResult = [String:AnyObject]()
                parsedResult["dataList"] = list
                callback(false, parsedResult)
```

im parsing data from an http request. i get this error:

Cannot assign value of type [AnyObject] to type AnyObject?

isn't a list of AnyObject, still an object?

Comment: let parsedResult = [String:[AnyObject]]()

Comment: now im facing tis error: type Any has no subscript members. help? here is where it happened - if let accountKey = data?["account"]?["key"], let sessionID = data?["session"]?["id"]

Comment: "isn't a list of AnyObject, still an object?" No. `Array` is a struct, not an class, so it's a member of `Any` but not a member of `AnyObject`. Note that you'll want to get this `[String:Any]` parsed into a real (non-Any) data structure as quickly as you can; definitely don't store it in a property. Working with `Any` can quickly become maddening. Look at the new Swift 4 `JSONDecoder` that avoids this problem with `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: Thanks all! it worked! i'm new to ios! i come from Javascript, where the syntax makes way more sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
let parsedResult = [String:AnyObject]()
```

To:

```
var parsedResult: [String: Any] = [ : ]
```

And by the way declare `parsedResult` as `var` to be able to do `parsedResult["dataList"] = list`.

For your other issue that you placed a comment on, do this instead:

```
if let account = data?["account"] as? [String: Any], let accountKey = account["key"] as? Int { ... }
```

Comment: This worked! but now im facing tis error: type Any has no subscript members. help? here is where it happened - if let accountKey = data?["account"]?["key"], let sessionID = data?["session"]?["id"]

Comment: @ryanwaite28, checkout the edited post. Do it like that `if let account = data?["account"] as? [String: Any], let accountKey = account["key"] as? Int { ... } `

Comment: Thanks all! it worked! i'm new to ios! i come from Javascript, where the syntax makes way more sense :)

Comment: Accepted, Done!